how to check whether a QNX system is running in ticking or tickless mode?
how to check whether a QNX system is running in ticking or tickless mode?
I have a board with QNX 7.1 and I want to understand how the system was configured - tickless or ticking. It is advisable to understand this at runtime. If this is not possible, what settings should I look for in the sources?
